# Flutter testing find.pageBack() on IOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I use flutter_driver and gherkin for test my app.

I want to use action to page back (find.pageBack()) but the Flutter Driver doesn't found the button on IOS emulator. On Android, it's ok.

I don't have any error just a timeout : `TimeoutException after 0:00:10.000000: Future not completed`

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gherkin/flutter_gherkin.dart';
import 'package:gherkin/gherkin.dart';

class NavValidation extends ThenWithWorld<FlutterWorld> {
  @override
  Future<void> executeStep() async {
    await FlutterDriverUtils.getText(world.driver, find.text('sagittarius / yesterday'));
    await FlutterDriverUtils.tap(world.driver, find.pageBack());
  }

  RegExp get pattern => RegExp(r"user should land on result screen");
}
```

Comment: Are you using different locale than English? find.pageBack() relies in "Back" literal and does not work if the device locale is different than english